# checksum error while install R using brew on MacOS Big Sur

Tags: r, macos, homebrew

I'm trying to install R through brew and I get the following error. Here is the snippet

```
==> Pouring r--4.1.0_1.big_sur.bottle.tar.gz
Error: Couldn't find manifest matching bottle checksum.
Please report this issue:
  https://docs.brew.sh/Troubleshooting
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/software_spec.rb:400:in `tab_attributes'
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/formula.rb:2339:in `bottle_tab_attributes'
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/utils/bottles.rb:100:in `load_tab'
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/formula_installer.rb:1154:in `pour'
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/formula_installer.rb:394:in `install'
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/install.rb:303:in `install_formula'
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/cmd/install.rb:207:in `block in install'
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/cmd/install.rb:205:in `each'
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/cmd/install.rb:205:in `install'
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/brew.rb:131:in `<main>'
```

I also did the following and they are all fine:

```
brew update
brew doctor
brew upgrade
```

I'm not sure how to address the error. I tried `brew install checksum` but there is nothing by that name.

Answer (score -1):

I have r 4.1.0 on Catalina. Trying to upgrade to 4.1.0_1 end up with the same error. But it works when I try to upgrade again.

```
brew upgrade r
```

Not sure if it could work for you to try to install again?